# Change a JOptionPane's button text color

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I would like to change the button text color *of one of the options* of a JOptionPane dialog to be different from the default color in Java Swing. So far, I've found some answers on how to do this for the entire application, but no answers for how to do this for one specific button.

The way I'm displaying the dialog (documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object))):

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null, // parent
    "Body text", 
    "Title text", 
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
    null, // icon
    new String[]{"Continue", "Cancel"}, 
    "Cancel");
```

I would like the "Continue" button to have red text color instead, but want all other JOptionPane button text colors in my app to remain the same.

Comment: Instead of passing an array of `String`s, pass an array of `JButton`s configured to your desired state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - simply use HTML formatting to set the button text color:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null, // parent
    "Body text", 
    "Title text", 
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
    null, // icon
    new String[]{"<html><font color=#ff0000>Continue</font></html>", "Cancel"}, 
    "Cancel");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `JOptionPane` is a vey flexible and curious class.

If you read the documentation for [`JOptionPane#showOptionDialog(Component, Object, String, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int,int,javax.swing.Icon,java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object)) you will find that the parameter `options` states:

> `options` - an array of objects indicating the possible choices the
> user can make; **if the objects are components, they are rendered
> properly**; non-String objects are rendered using their `toString`
> methods; if this parameter is `null`, the options are determined by
> the Look and Feel

(emphasis added by me)

This basically means you can pass your own configured `JButton`s via the `options` parameter and they will be "rendered properly".

Having said that, it will take some additional work to make work as "normal" (ie returning the index of the option that was selected).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showOptions();
            }
        });
    }

    protected JOptionPane getOptionPane(JComponent parent) {
        JOptionPane pane = null;
        if (!(parent instanceof JOptionPane)) {
            pane = getOptionPane((JComponent) parent.getParent());
        } else {
            pane = (JOptionPane) parent;
        }
        return pane;
    }

    public void showOptions() {
        final JButton okay = new JButton("Ok");
        okay.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane pane = getOptionPane((JComponent) e.getSource());
                pane.setValue(okay);
            }
        });
        final JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane pane = getOptionPane((JComponent) e.getSource());
                pane.setValue(cancel);
            }
        });

        int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null,
                "Happiness and Joy",
                "Get",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                new Object[]{okay, cancel},
                okay);
        System.out.println(option);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the additional setup / extra code is not optimal. In the end, I figured it out using HTML formatting, meaning we wouldn't have the issue of additional setup to make buttons work as "normal" like you mentioned - with just one line of code :)

Comment: The added benefit, you can control the button state, change the tooltips, what ever you want - but what ever meets your needs

Comment: @JornRigter MadProgrammer is right. This particular project seems small, so it probably isn't a problem, but once you get to any sort of scale, this will become a very hard to find bug later on. Yesterday's solutions become the problems of today.

Comment: Yes, there can be benefits for sure -- Thanks for those insights, that's helpful. For this purpose, where I just want to update the button text color, using html formatting works with a lot less code, and I don't expect any bugs to come from that. If this would start getting more complex I'd probably go for this option, but following Google's coding guidelines; don't optimize for problems you don't have yet :). Thanks guys!